# How do classes and methods work in R and whats the most convenient way to use them?

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some object oriented programming in R. Im familiar with OOP syntax from other languages like Python and Java, but i don't understand how classes work in R.

I've found some examples are sources online but none of them are explained, its just raw code which seems to not make any sense.

Could you please tell me how a simple python class like the following can be written in R, with some explination:

```
class Num():
    def __init__(self, number):
         self.data = number
    def print_number(self):
         print(self.data)
```

Comment: You might find this useful: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html

Comment: A better reference would be here: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html It's the newer edition of the Advanced R book, and it's the section with all the different OOP systems in R rather than just S3, which is the weakest OOP system of them all. Hristmar, OOP in R is a somewhat complex topic. The link I gave will alleviate your criticism of other sources; it is certainly **not** just code with no explanation. It will have lots of explanation. But, fair warning, it's complicated. There are multiple different answers to how to make the simple class you present there, each with their own pros & cons